# Returning an enum, can't understand the line of code

Tags: c++, enums

I am studying the code from an existing project and I read this piece of code:

```
enum Score {
  SCORE_ZERO,
  SCORE_ENSURE_INTEGER_SIZE_P = INT_MAX,
  SCORE_ENSURE_INTEGER_SIZE_N = INT_MIN
};

inline Score make_score(int mg, int eg) {
  return Score((mg << 16) + eg);
}
```

I have an enumeration called `Score` and a function that returns a `Score`. I don't understand what the last line means. Does it "create" and then return a `Score` enumeration passing an integer to it? Where does the integer go? How is it saved?

Comment: `mg` is shifted 16 bits to the left. `eg` is added to the result. The sum is turned into a `Score`, which is then returned. Not sure what you mean by ‘*saved*’.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks for the answer. What I mean is that I don't understand how the sum is turned into a `Score`. What will be the difference between two resulting `Score` with a different integer value?

Comment: Enums are just a layer over an underlying integral type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Score` is a C-style enumerated type. `SCORE_ZERO`, etc. are names for particular values, but an object of the enumerated type can hold **any** value that fits in the type. In this case, it can hold any `int` value. So you could say, for example,

```
Score temp = 13;
```

That final line is creating a temporary with an `int` value and returning that temporary. A verbose version would look like this:

```
Score temp = (mg << 16) + eg;
return temp;
```

It's assuming that each of `mg` and `eg` fit into 16 bits, and packing the middle game and end game scores into a single value of the enumerated type.